# Debugging program in DnSpy

Tags: c#, debugging

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCofy.jpg)

I started try debugging with DnSpy.
but when I chose "Debug(F5)",it asks me to specify assembly.

what does "assembly" in this case?
from where I can get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assemblies are the names given to .net executables and dlls.  In this case, it means, what program do you want to debug.